# How to change UserCreationForm attributes such as error_messges, labels etc.?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I Want to change default label of django UserCreationForm which I imported from django.contrib.auth.forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
       model = models.User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

E.g. here, how should I change the default label or error message of username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`UserCreationForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) already has fields in it, so use `labels` and `error_messages` dictionary to override attributes inside `Meta` class.

According to docs:

> **labels** is a dictionary of model field names mapped to a label.

> **error_messages** is a dictionary of model field names mapped to a dictionary of error messages.

Try this:

```py
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
       model = models.User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
       labels={
           "username": "custom label for username"
       }
       error_messages={
           "username": {
               "required": "custom message for required"
            }
       }
```

Comment: it works but for password1 and password2 I can't change the label with this way
do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @sadegh Since the main field is `password1`, another field is only for confirming.

Comment: @sadegh For changing `password2` also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72078170/17562044), you should again define the fields and use inline attributes in that.